# jQuery - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new in jQuery and Java and i am trying to build a simple application with those two and JSON messages.i am trying to retrieve the data from my database, but when i click the button nothing happens. Google's tool show the error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/WebLibrary/LibraryBooks 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-latest.min.js:4 

send @ jquery-latest.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-latest.min.js:4
m.(anonymous function) @ jquery-latest.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ save_book:19
dispatch @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
```

I have read some similar questions and answers but i could't fix it.My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tablediv").hide();
         $("#showBooks").click(function(event){
               $.get('LibraryBooks',function(responseJson) {
                if(responseJson!=null){
                    $("#booktable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    var table1 = $("#booktable");
                    $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                         var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>");
                            rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['title']); 
                            rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['author_name']); 
                            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['author_surname']); 
                            rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['year']); 
                            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                    });
                    }
                });
         $("#tablediv").show();   
      });      
    });
</script>
```

And doGet method from LibraryBooks servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        ArrayList<BookObject> books = new ArrayList<BookObject>();
        books = FetchData.getAllBooks();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(books, new TypeToken<BookObject>() {}.getType());

        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
    }
```

If there is need for some extra code please let me know.

Comment: Did you look at the server logs for the error message?

Comment: I tried but i can't find such file, unless i forgot to search somewhere.